# Selenium Java - Esperar a que un elemento esté presente y realizar una acción

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

Mi codigo es:

```
  //El .//*[@id='main'] me representa el cuerpo del mensaje que me aparece del error de la pagina http:pruebaauaomation.com
    if (Obj_Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']")).isDisplayed()){
//Al detectar el error por el xpath entonces mandará la siguiente pagina
                Obj_Driver.get("http://ENLACEAIDENTIFICAR.com");

            }
            else if( 
// El html/body es el xpath del mensaje de error de http://ENLACEAIDENTIFICAR.com 
Obj_Driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body")).isDisplayed()){
    --// El html/body hace referencia al xpath del cuerpo del mensaje que aparece en la  pagina
                    Obj_Driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body")).sendKeys(Key.F5); 

            }
```

[image: Imagen del error de http:pruebaauaomation.com]
Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que cuando ingreso a una URL http:pruebaauaomation.com (aveces) me sale ese mensaje de error, el xpath de la imagen es (ver imagen 1) lo que quiero hacer es que cuando salga ese mensaje me envíe la URL que se llama: http:ENLACEAIDENTIFICAR.com ... Algunas veces la URL http:ENLACEAIDENTIFICAR.com no carga por X o Y motivo (cuando no carga la pagina lanza un mensaje que dice: (No se puede acceder a la pagina), entonces lo que quiero hacer es que cuando no cargue la pagina mande un F5 tantas veces hasta que cargue definitivamente la pagina...

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

para esperar que cargue algún elemento, como en tu caso es un texto, podrías implementar algo como esto:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(TU_DRIVER, 10000);
    WebElement ELEMENTO_A_ESPERAR = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_aqui")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola con el siguiente codigo puedes comprobar si el elemento que buscas esta presente o no durante el periodo de tiempo que indica la variable seconds, cada RETRY_TIME segundos:

```
if (new FluentWait<WebDriver>(Obj_Driver)
            .withTimeout(seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(RETRY_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions
                    .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath))) != null)
{
    Obj_Driver.get("http://ENLACEAIDENTIFICAR.com");
}
```

Pero puede que el problema este en el segundo xpath, ya que el 99% de las paginas web tienen un "html/body"